# hyperlink with beamer using lyx

Tags: beamer, lyx, links

I am using LyX to build a `beamer` presentation that has hyperlinks.  I create the hyperlink in the following manner:

```
\hyperlink{test}{\beamerbutton{mybutton}}
```

Then, there is a frame after the `\appendix` command in my file which (from LyX source has):

```
\lyxframe{Test Slide\label{test}}
hello lyx!    
\lyxframeend{}
```

However, the link seems to go to the slide *after* this one. What is going on here? However, using the `\hypertarget` command works fine:

```
\lyxframe{Test Slide}
\hypertarget{test}{}
hello lyx!    
\lyxframeend{}
```

Comment: What happens if you put the label *after* `\lyxframe{blurgh}`, like this: `\lyxframe{Test Slide}\label{test}hello lyx\lyxframeend{}`?

Comment: Alex, for him/her to be notified of your comment, you should poke him with @moewe

Comment: @moewe: your comment worked, turn it into an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get proper hyperlinks you need to use `\label{test}` *after* `\lyxframe{blurgh}`.

Like this

```
\lyxframe{Test Slide}\label{test}
  hello lyx
\lyxframeend{}
```

If LaTeX encounters a `\label`, it sets a link to where the last counter-modification appeared. If you use `\label` within the command modifying the counter alls sorts of things may happen, but probably not what you expect.